# Nsupdate module in ansible causes an error

Tags: module, ansible, dns, bind, named

When i try to run the following .yml role i get an error with nsupdate.

I am using centos7 and the machine is running bind.

When i do nsupdate with either the original DNS server or the ansible master i can update the records, only when i use the nsupdate module it doesn't work, any help? ty!

`tasks/main.yml`

This is the part with the relevant code

```
- name: Add or modify ansible.example.org A to 192.168.1.1"
  community.general.nsupdate:
    server: "10.0.0.40"
    zone: "ben.com."
    record: "ansible"
    value: "192.168.1.1"
  when: ansible_eth1.ipv4.address == '10.0.0.40'
```

The error:

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
fatal: [10.0.0.40]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 10.0.0.40 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1624977590.7-4712-16053022547656/AnsiballZ_nsupdate.py\", line 102, in <module>\r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1624977590.7-4712-16053022547656/AnsiballZ_nsupdate.py\", line 94, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1624977590.7-4712-16053022547656/AnsiballZ_nsupdate.py\", line 40, in invoke_module\r\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible_collections.community.general.plugins.modules.nsupdate', init_globals=None, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 176, in run_module\r\n    fname, loader, pkg_name)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 82, in _run_module_code\r\n    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 72, in _run_code\r\n    exec code in run_globals\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_community.general.nsupdate_payload_xAhaGd/ansible_community.general.nsupdate_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/modules/nsupdate.py\", line 189, in <module>\r\n  File \"build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/dns/update.py\", line 21, in <module>\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dnspython-2.1.1.dev77+gf61a939-py2.7.egg/dns/message.py\", line 201\r\n    s.write(f';{name}\\n')\r\n                       ^\r\nSyntaxError: invalid syntax\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
```

`relevant line in traceback`

```
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/dns/update.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dnspython-2.1.1.dev77+gf61a939-py2.7.egg/dns/message.py", line 201
    s.write(f';{name}\n')
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You are running Python3 code (the `f'...'`) part under Python2, hence it does not work and raise a SyntaxError. But other than that your question is offtopic here as not related to programming. You need to find appropriate venues for help on Ansible.

Comment: How is a question about two coding languages not related to programming?
There are many ansible questions on this site.

If you can i would love help on how to fix this.

Comment: Your question is about an error in Ansible. Ansible is not a programming language but a deployment tool. The fact that there are other offtopic questions is not a reason to add another offtopic one. And as much as you want to have help, it does not grant the right to ignore the rules of the website you are in.

Answer (score -1):

Problem was that it was prolly running on the wrong interpeter on the host machine like @Patrick mentioned..
Fixed it by adding host group vars like so:

```
[DNS_Master:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python3.9
```